# Which libraries are included in the Scopus citation database?

Tags: literature-review, scopus

Is there a list of libraries which are included in the Scopus database?

I am working in the field of Human Computer Interaction and searching for a list of included libraries (e.g. ACM, AIS and so on).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Scopus manages their indexing by what you call "Libraries" (you probably mean publishers, and I agree that many publishers seem to call their online publishing platforms something like "digital library"). Instead, Scopus selects individual **titles** for indexing. That means that not all titles offered in a specific "library" may be contained in the database. Scopus offers a list of titles they are indexing on [their website](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/content), which you could use to research the titles that you are interested in.

Comment: okay - maybe "including" in the search index is the right definition. I mean also ACM is calling their "platform" the ACM digital library and I thought Scopus (writting in a lot of review papers) is also including some of those "libraries" by working as a meta-search tool...

Comment: @ateam That's not correct. Scopus selects individual journals on the basis of their reckoning of quality. Despite being owned by Elsevier, Scopus don't index all of Elsevier's journals. https://awayofhappening.wordpress.com/2016/04/28/counting-elsevier-publications-indexed-in-scopus/

Comment: alright, so I can't say that all the papers which are available on ACM appear on Scopus because of their "reckoning of quality" algorithm?

Comment: @ateam Probably not, but to figure out, you could make a list of all titles on the ACM platform, a list of all ACM titles in Scopus, and see whether it's the same.

Comment: @MJeffryes Interesting link, thank's for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I have little to add to silvado's spot-on answer, but to answer an implied question: If your study is in HCI, then why not use ACM Digital Library citation counts? Why do you want to use Scopus? The idea of citation counts is that you want to see how many times all relevant literature has cited you studies of interest. In my view, any rigorous citation analysis study should use at least two sources:

- Google Scholar: This is the biggest citation database, and captures almost everything, with no concern about the quality of the referring articles. Every other citation database is pretty much a subset of what Google Scholar captures.
- At least one other relevant citation database: "Relevant" means that the citation database in question specializes on the topic area of interest, normally including almost all high-quality sources in the field. For HCI, this is doubtlessly ACM Digital Library (ACMDL)--HCI is a very explicit focus for ACM. ACMDL would probably have lower citation counts than Scopus, since Scopus includes far more sources, but in a sense they would "count" more, since they better reflect how much the articles have been cited in the HCI community.

I'm not sure if this captures your intent, but it is worth considering. If so, then it would render your concern moot about what exactly Scopus might or might not index.